# Increase the speed for animation css3

Tags: css, animation

```
.bg-grass{
width: 100%; 
height: 290px; 
background-size: :100%;
background-image: url(../graphic/background/001.png);
background-position: 0px 0px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
animation: animatedBackground 20s linear infinite;
-ms-animation: animatedBackground 20s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: animatedBackground 20s linear infinite;
-webkit-animation: animatedBackground 20s linear infinite;
```

}

```
.grass-speed2{
animation: animatedBackground 5s linear infinite;
-ms-animation: animatedBackground 5s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: animatedBackground 5s linear infinite;
-webkit-animation: animatedBackground 5s linear infinite ;
```

}

I have two css classes which one is to have a normal animation and another to make it faster. The scenario would be that at certain time, the grass-speed2 class would be added into bg-grass to make the speed faster. It works fine in firefox but its not working in chrome. Am not sure why. Also is there a way to make it continue which background position it is currently at when the speed is being increased?

**EDIT 1**

I have forgotten to add in the keyframe css

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
from { background-position: 0 0; }
to { background-position: 100% 0; }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

This might be better handled through the use of animation key-frames. Instead of using different classes, try perhaps using different percentages in the key-frames combined with seconds. Here is an example using `top`. Of course, you can replace this (or add more) with the more appropriate animation type.

```
@keyframes animatedTop {
    0% {
        top: 0;
    }
    90% {
        top: 5px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 8px;
    } 
}
```

Remember to include the prefixes.

```
/* @-webkit-
   @-moz-
   @-o-
*/
```

And you can call your animation by using.

```
.myClass {
    animation: animatedTop 15s;
}
```

Comment: hi linday, I already have a keyframe which I have just updated. So you are suggesting for me to make multiple keyframes to make the speed faster?

Comment: Hi @lilsizzo ! I would suggest making one animation class, and then using multiple keyframes (you could have as many as 0% - 100% [so, it could be 1%, 2% etc.]) to adjust the time. 

As an aside, I've not tried making a keyframe that occurs from 0.01% to 0.1% before. Maybe that technique could create even greater slowness.

Answer (score 0):

Please upload your code some where and make a demo so that we can figure-out the real problem.
Just a quick note, remember to add browser vender prefix before keyframe css as well:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground{...}
@-moz-keyframes animateBackground{...}
@-o-keyframes animateBackground{....}
```

Probably this may solve your problem.

Enjoy css keyframe animation!